# Can two Node servers run simultaneously and interact, so that one is mediator serving a client?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, node.js, express, socket.io

I've modified some code from a [simple chat tutorial](http://psitsmike.com/2011/09/node-js-and-socket-io-chat-tutorial/) in a very basic way so that I have a JavaScript chatbot sitting on a NodeJS server which immediately sends a response to the client when the user inputs something.

This is the relevant part of the code on the NodeJS server, which works:

```
socket.on('sendchat', function (data) {
    // we tell the client to execute 'updatechat' with 2 parameters
    io.sockets.emit('updatechat', socket.username, data);
    // we also tell the client to send the bot's response
    io.sockets.emit('updatechat', 'BOT', bot.transform(data));
});
```

So the bot's response is very much tied up with the user's input. I want to now put the bot on a different node server so that the chat can deliver and react to the bot in the same way as it does the user, and so that the bot can process and act independently. Roughly:

**USER (client/browser) `<--->` MEDIATOR (Node server 1) `<--->` CHAT BOT (Node server 2)**

...

I have tried what seemed to me to be the obvious thing to do (which was also obviously wrong), which is take this line from my client:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080'); // 8080 being the port for the other server
```

I dropped this into my server-side js file like so:

```
var app = require('express').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
app.listen(8080);

var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
```

But this produces an error in the node console to say that the `io` object has no method `connect`. Perhaps this is because `connect` belongs only to the client-side JS script. Is there an easy way for me to have my Node server interact with another Node server without hacking up the client-side library?

More fundamentally, is it even possible to run two node servers at once and have one be a mediator to pass and receive messages from another before pushing to the client? I am using using the Express framework (v2.4.6) and socket.io (v0.8.4), but I'm open to other suggestions.

Comment: are you using express 3 ?

Comment: @soyuka Apparently not. Seems to be version 2.4.6 according to package.json. I'll put this in my question. Is it worth updating the module?

Comment: This link helped me : http://psitsmike.com/2011/10/node-js-and-socket-io-multiroom-chat-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks for the link; it's interesting. I might need to clarify my question above but what I'm trying to achieve is multithreading, so that I can have a chatbot process a user input even while a central process (like for example saving or retrieving data about a conversation) is ongoing. Hence my interest in running two servers (locally) and having them interact. Do the rooms mentioned in the tutorial allow for multithreadedness?

Comment: I've clarified question in the hope that what I am trying to do will make more sense and that this will attract more attention, preferably in the form of answers :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code. One should use

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
socket.on('updatechat', function(data) {
...
sockets.emit('User',{'user': 'login'});
sockets.emit('User',{'data': data});
});
});
```

Use socket.emit not io.sockets.emit.
io.sockets.emit will send to all the clients.
Also you cannot drop the same line from the client on the server !!!, use the following to connect to another server from node.

```
var ioc = require('socket.io-client');         //ioc
var socket2 = ioc.connect('server2:8080');   //socket2
```

Rest you can figure out: 
client -> socket -> server -> socket2 -> server2

Update : socket.io-client is a separate package that needs to be installed for this to work. See here: https://npmjs.org/package/socket.io-client

Simply do this for installation `npm install socket.io-client`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you when you say there are mistakes. The code I gave above for the `emit` actually works. It's taken almost verbatim from Michael Mukhin's tutorial and I've just added a couple extra lines of code to introduce a chatbot (which almost like an echobot at this point). I tried your tip about requiring `socket.io-client` but it gave me an error. I'll look into this a bit more.

Comment: Not semantic error but logical, sockets.emit sends only to the connected user but io.sockets.emit broadcasts to all connected clients (I assumed it was one-to-one chat). What kind of error are you getting ? socket.io-client is a package that has to be installed via npm. It is separate from socket.io. Here is the npm page: https://npmjs.org/package/socket.io-client

Comment: It's one-to-one chat I'm primarily interested in but the code from the tutorial allows for more (I've tested it with three users). I'll take a look at the logics you mention as it will probably help me understand what's happening more clearly. As for the error: it says that it can't find `socket.io-client`. I wasn't aware it could be installed separately though; I saw the module in the `node_modules` folder for socket.io and tried various ways of reaching it, e.g., `.\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client`. I'll try installing it as you suggest and report back. Thx for yr patient responses.

Comment: It turns out you were right; I simply needed to install socket.io-client, which I hadn't realised was a separate package. Many thanks! I upvoted your answer naturally, but if you could edit it to include the line about installing the package and include the link you gave me I'll mark it correct. Thanks again :-)

Comment: Just an additional thing, npm can be used to install individual packages as above, but it can also be used to meet all dependencies for a project. If you run "nmp install" in your project folder, and your dependencies are listed in a file called "packages.json" (documented here http://package.json.nodejitsu.com/) then all dependencies required will be installed in to node_modules.